# How can I determine if a complex matrix is positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

By definition, a matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite if $\langle A\vec x, \vec x \rangle \ge 0 $ for all $\vec x \in V$ where $V$ is an inner-product space. Consider the matrix

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&i\newline i&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

How can I determine if this matrix is positive semidefinite?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well, let $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \newline x_2\end{bmatrix}$, then $Ax = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 + ix_2 \newline ix_1 + x_2\end{bmatrix}$ so $\langle Ax, x\rangle = x_1^2 + 2ix_1x_2 + x_2^2$ I don't know what to do at this point.

Comment: You have to take the conjugate of one of the vectors since they're complex. You may want to expand $x_1=a+bi$ and $x_2=c+di$ to better understand what's going on.

Comment: What is $x = (i,0)$?

Comment: Unless you’re using some weird custom definition (like just looking at real parts), it doesn’t make sense to talk about a positive definite complex matrix - you can’t say whether a complex number is greater than 0.

Comment: If $A$ can be a complex matrix, then $\langle Ax,x \rangle$ can be non-real number, so usually you cannot talk about it being greater than or less than $0$.

Comment: A matrix is positive semidefinite if for any $x$ we have $\langle Ax,x\rangle \ge 0,$ i.e.  (a) the quantity is a real number, (b) it is nonnegative. If for some $x$ the quantity is not a real number the matrix is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: Your matrix is not Hermitian

Comment: @Eric Isn't that why $A$ is supposed to be Hermitian?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. If $A$ were Hermitian, then it’d be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> A $n\times n$ **Hermitian** complex matrix  $A$ is said to be positive-definite (positive semi-definite) if $\langle Ax,x \rangle > 0$ $\left(\langle Ax,x \rangle \geq 0\right)$.

A matrix is hermitian if $A=A^{H}$ ($A$ is equal to it's conjugate transpose), which is not satisfied by your matrix.

I therefore simply assume you are given a hermitian matrix.
In that case definition does make sense since $\langle Ax,x \rangle \in \mathbb{R}$ which can be proved using the fact that hermitian matrices are self-adjoint ($A=A^{H}=A^{\ast}$). Using the properties of the inner product it follows that
$$\alpha 
:=
\langle Ax,x\rangle
=
\overline{\langle x,Ax\rangle}
=
\overline{\langle A^{\ast}x,\rangle}
=
\overline{\langle Ax,x\rangle}
=\overline{\alpha}
$$ and hence $\alpha=\overline{\alpha}$ which is only true for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Assuming $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle $ is the canonical inner product on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ given by $$\langle x,y \rangle := y^{H}x=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\overline{y}_{i}$$
you can can check if $A$ is positive definite (semi-definit) by calculating whether
$$\langle Ax,x \rangle 
=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_{i}\overline{x_{j}}
>0 (\geq 0)
$$ for all $x\in \mathbb{C}^{n}$.

For example for the matrix
$$
A
=
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & i \\
-i & 1 \end{array} \right)
$$ we get
$$\begin{align}
\langle Ax, x \rangle
&=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_{i}\overline{x_{j}}\\
&=
a_{11}x_{1}\overline{x_{1}}+a_{22}x_{2}\overline{x_{2}}+a_{12}x_{1}\overline{x_{2}}+a_{21}x_{2}\overline{x_{1}}\\
&=
a_{11}|x_{1}|^{2}+a_{22}|x_{2}|^{2}+a_{12}x_{1}\overline{x_{2}}+\overline{a_{12}}x_{2}\overline{x_{1}}\\
&=
a_{11}|x_{1}|^{2}+a_{22}|x_{2}|^{2}+a_{12}x_{1}\overline{x_{2}}+\overline{a_{12}x_{1}\overline{x_{2}}}\\
&=
a_{11}|x_{1}|^{2}+a_{22}|x_{2}|^{2}+2Re(a_{12}x_{1}\overline{x_{2}})
\end{align}
$$.
Plugin in the values of $A$ this yields
$\begin{align}
\langle Ax, x \rangle=|x_{1}|^{2}+|x_{2}|^{2}+2Re(ix_{1}\overline{x_{2}})
\end{align}
$
which can be further simplified by writing $x_{1}:=a+bi$ and x_{2}=c+di$.

Then $Re(ix_{1}x_{2})=Re(i(a+bi)(c+di)=i(ac-bd+adi+bci))=-(ad+bc)$ and $|x_{1}|^2=a^2+b^2$, $|x_{2}|^2=c^2+d^2$. Plugging in yields

$$
\begin{align}
\langle Ax, x\rangle
&=
|x_{1}|^{2}+|x_{2}|^{2}+2Re(ix_{1}=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-2ad-2bc\\
&=
a^{2}-2ad+c^{2}+b^{2}-2bc+d^{2}\\
&=
|(a-c)+(b-c)i|^{2}\\
&=
|(x_1 - x_2)|^2 \geq 0
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is positive (semi)definite if all of its eigenvalue values are positive (nonnegative)reals.

A matrix’s complex quadratic form will always gives real values iff it is Hermitian.

If your restrict your vectors to real numbers, then it’s possible to have a non-symmetric  positive definite matrix, but that doesn’t apply to this instance.

A Hermitian matrix is positive (semi)definite iff all of its eigenvalues are positive (nonnegative). This is clear by diagonalizing the matrix and then considering what happens to the unit vectors.

Your matrix $A$ is not Hermitian, so it’s not semidefinite.

If you did have a 2x2 Hermitian matrix, then the two eigenvalues are nonnegative iff their sum is nonnegative and their product is nonnegative, so it suffices to check whether the trace and determinant are both nonnegative. For larger matrices, this is necessary but not sufficient (ex: 3x3 matrix with eigenvalues $-1,-1,3$).

For example, if you replaced one of the $i$’s with $-i$ in your matrix $A$, then it would be Hermitian with trace $1+1=2$ and determinant $1\cdot 1-i\cdot(-i)=0$, so it would be positive semidefinite. Solving the eigenvalues explicitly gives $0,2 \geq 0$.